# use pagination for limited records in laravel 5.2

Tags: pagination, laravel-5, take

I am trying to use paginate method for 12 records. I need 12 results where first 6 results comes in first page and the rest 6 results in second page. I used the below code in the controller,

```
$collection = User::take(12)->whereHas('roles', function($q) {
            $q->where('slug', 'member');

        }
        )->where('status','1')->OrderBy('last_login','desc');
```

I used take() to get 12 records and used paginate(6) to display 6 results in one page as this,

```
$collection = $collection->paginate(6);
return View('preferred_matches')->with(array('collection'=>$collection));
```

In my view , I gave links like this,

```
{{ $collection->links() }}
```

But the take(12) is not working. 6 results appears in each page ,but more than 12 results are displaying. How can I use limited records for pagination. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of `take` you can try `limit(12)`

Comment: but still , it has no effect. What I need is to display 12 records , 6 results per page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel does not support limit on its default pagination, but if limit can be placed on pagination with the following steps:

First create a static method inside a model (Suppose User Model)

**First step:** Add this two line after namespace of User model

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

**Second step:**  inside User model just type the below method

```
public static function customPaginate($items,$perPage)
{
    //Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    //Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
    $collection = new Collection($items);

    //Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
    $perPage = $perPage;

    //Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
    $currentPageSearchResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();

    //Create our paginator and pass it to the view
    $paginatedSearchResults = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($collection), $perPage);

   return $paginatedSearchResults;
}
```

**Third step:** In route or controller type the code to see the result (suppose in `routes.php`)

```
Route::get('/', function(){
   $users = DB::table('users')->limit(20)->get();
   $paginated_result = App\User::customPaginate($users,3);
   //dd($paginated_result);
   return view('show')->with('paginated_result',$paginated_result);
});
```

Hopefully, It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight update about the previous answer, there is a slight bug if the collection is less than the `perPage` parameter, the items array is empty, this can be fix by replacing :

`$currentPageSearchResults = $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all();`

by

`$currentPageSearchResults = ($items->count() > $perPage) ? $collection->slice($currentPage * $perPage, $perPage)->all() : $collection->all();`

in the static function.
Thanks for this @sabuz ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just one more update about the previous answer, if you try to access the data of "last page" it will bring a empty result, to fix this you just have to change this line:

`$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();`

for these two:

`$currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
 $currentPage = $currentPage - 1;`

I hope it helps someone...